# Could not access the Package Manager. Is the system running?

Tags: android-package-managers

I'm trying to install an app on my phone using pm function but all the time I get this error: "Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?". I cannot run any command that starts with pm without getting this error. How can I fix this?

root@tblte:/storage/emulated/0/tmp # ls
ls
du.log
logcat.apk
sulog_247.txt
root@tblte:/storage/emulated/0/tmp # pm install logcat.apk
pm install logcat.apk
Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?
root@tblte:/storage/emulated/0/tmp # pm list
pm list
Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?
root@tblte:/storage/emulated/0/tmp #

Thank you.

Comment: Solved by installing the latest SuperSU.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by installing the latest SuperSU.

Answer (score 0):

open cmd or terminal  and write this

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

[Could not access the Package Manager](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/226670/#Comment_226670)